# Keycloak integration to an existing JHipster JWT app while keeping the JWT authentication process

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, jwt, keycloak, jhipster

I have an existing JHipster application generated with the JWT authentication process. Which means that user accounts are handled by the application itself. And every user have to log in with his username and password directly into the application.

Now we are developping some microservices and mobile apps that will communicate with the first JHipster app. And for that, we want to use Keycloak to manage the authentication process for the microservices and mobile apps, while keeping the existing JWT authentication process.

What we want is that: users with username and password will log in directly to the application (they will not be redirected to Keycloak to authenticate), and the microservices and mobile apps will need tokens from Keycloak (by sending the client id and secret to Keycloak) to get access to the JHipster app resources.

All the tutorials that I saw are about replacing the JWT authentication process by Keycloak.  With this, every user will be redirected to Keycloak, and we don't want that for now (maybe in the future we will upgrade all of that).

Please if you have any resource that can help me, it will be nice.

Comment: There are many resources about using multiple authentication providers in spring security.

Comment: @Burkinabé, Did you solve your problem? If yes, how?

Comment: @SparX I solve my problem. Jhipster uses JJWT to handle JWT authentication process. So, take a look at the documentation [here](https://github.com/jwtk/jjwt). You will need to read the [signing key resolver section] (https://github.com/jwtk/jjwt#signing-key-resolver) to understand how to make app recognize its own tokens and keycloak tokens. The class you will need to edit is `TokenProvider`.